# Haskell aeson ParseJSON example using (.:)

Tags: haskell, aeson

There is the following snippet of code in the Aeson package usage [example](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.9.0.1/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:FromJSON):

```
data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Double }

instance FromJSON Coord where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Coord    <$>
                         v .: "x" <*>
                         v .: "y"
```

The type of `parseJSON` function is `parseJSON :: Value -> Parser a`.
I have the following question about this code: what is the `.:` function? From the example I might say that its type is `Object -> String -> Parser String`, however I can't find anything about it on hoogle/hackage. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The [index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.9.0.1/docs/doc-index.html) linked to at the top of documentation pages often helps in such cases.

Comment: @duplode Thanks a lot, that basically answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It retrieves the value associated with the key. `(.:)` produces a parse failure (via `empty` from `Alternative`) if the key isn't there, so it is suitable for mandatory keys (as opposed to `(.:?)`, which makes sense for optional ones).